# Codeigniter in LAMP on Arch Linux

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I installed and setup LAMP + PhpMyAdmin. I did mod_rewrite etc. now I'm can access to rewrite and I did permission. But I can access without post in controller ($this->input->post('buton_ismi')) but I cannot access with it. Please help me. Here it's my codes. It's working on godaddy and ubuntu lamp. but not working in php7.1.4 on arch linux

Depo.php (Contoller-veriler() function it's working) 
I'm accessing with http://localhost/belle/depo/veriler address ;

```
function veriler() {
    $this->load->helper('url'); //url helper'dan base_url fonksiyonunu çekmek için çağırıyoruz
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('depo_model');
    $data['veri'] = $this->depo_model->hepsini_al();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('depo_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

depo_view.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">   
        <?php foreach($veri as $row){ ?>
           <div class="col s6">
                <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div class="card-content white-text">
                    <span class="card-title"><?php echo $row->tour_nummer;?></span>
                        <p>
                            ID: <?php echo $row->id;?> </br>
                            Tour Nummer: <?php echo $row->tour_nummer;?> </br>
                            Name: <?php echo $row->name;?> </br>
                            Datum <?php echo $row->datum; ?> </br>
                            Ware Einladen: <?php echo $row->ware_einladen;?> </br>
                            Lager Ausfahrt: <?php echo $row->lager_ausfahrt;?> </br>
                            lager Ankunft: <?php echo $row->lager_ankunft;?> </br>
                            Bis: <?php echo $row->bis;?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('Depo/indir'); ?>">Download result as CSV</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Depo.php (Contoller-ozel($name) function it's not working) I'm accessing with http://localhost/belle/depo/ozel/John-Doe address;

```
public function ozel($name)
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');
                $this->load->model('depo_model');
                    if($this->input->post('buton_ismi'))//formda sumbit tuşuna basıldığında çalışacak fonksiyon
                        {  
                            $this->depo_model->veri_ekleme_fonksiyonu();  //yeni elemanı database eklemek için model dosyamızı çağırıyoruz
                        }
                    if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']))//formda sumbit tuşuna basıldığında çalışacak fonksiyon
                    {
                            $ftU = $_FILES['fileToUpload'];
                            $name = $_SESSION['username'];
                            $data['errorcode'] = $this->depo_model->upload_resim($ftU, $name);
                    }
                    if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload2']))//formda sumbit tuşuna basıldığında çalışacak fonksiyon
                    {
                            $ftU2 = $_FILES['fileToUpload2'];
                            $name = $_SESSION['username'];
                            $data['errorcode'] = $this->depo_model->upload_resim($ftU2, $name);
                    }
                $data['name'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('depo_ozel_view', $data);
                $this->load->view('footer');

    }
```

depo_ozel_view.php

```
<div class="container">
  <br><br>
  <!--h1 class="header center orange-text">Veri Ekle</h1-->
  <div class="row">

    <form action="<?php $urlname = $this->uri->segment(3); echo base_url('Depo/Ekle/'.$urlname); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="col m4 s12">

        Name: <input name="name_input" type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" readonly> 
        </div>
        <div class="col m4 s12">
        Tour nummer: <input name="tour_nummer_input" type="text" required> 
        </div>
        <div class="col m4 s12">
        Datum: <input name="datum_input" type="text" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y"); ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col m3 s12">
         Ware Einladen: <input name="ware_einladen_input" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col m3 s12">
        Lager Ausfahrt: <input name="lager_ausfahrt_input" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col m3 s12">
        Lager Ankunft: <input name="lager_ankunft_input" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col m3 s12">
        Bis :<input name="bis_input" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col m6 s12">
        Lieferschein Seite-1 : 
        <input name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" type="file" accept="image/*" class="file-loading" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col m6 s12">
        Lieferschein Seite-2 : 
        <input name="fileToUpload2" id="fileToUpload2" type="file" accept="image/*" class="file-loading" required>
        </div>
        <div class="center col m2 offset-m4 s12">
            </br>
            <button type="submit" name="buton_ismi" value="Sent" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light orange">Abschicken</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  </br>


  <br><br>

</div>
```

Here it's error page in http://localhost/belle/depo/ozel/John-Doe (Depo controller / ozel($name) function )

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Depo::$input

Filename: controllers/Depo.php

Line Number: 37

Backtrace:

File: /srv/http/belle/application/controllers/Depo.php
Line: 37
Function: _error_handler

File: /srv/http/belle/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function post() on null

Filename: /srv/http/belle/application/controllers/Depo.php

Line Number: 37

Backtrace:

File: /srv/http/belle/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

and 37th line:

```
if($this->input->post('buton_ismi')) //formda sumbit tuşuna basıldığında çalışacak fonksiyon
```

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L]
```

access_log

```
::1 - - [16/Apr/2017:21:41:45 +0300] "GET /belle/depo/ozel/John-Doe HTTP/1.1" 500 1047
```

Comment: If it is working on Ubuntu, but not on ArchLinux, compare the two configurations. Another approach would be removing directives from Ubuntu's configuration until it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I'm doing same configurations and permission it's really odd about the some page working some page is not working o.O

Comment: My idea is about the default configuration when you install Apache, etc. Usually this differs with distributions.

Comment: Since you've got message `Message: Undefined property: Depo::$input` that means `Input` library is not loaded. Most likely because of not included parent class constructor in `Depo` class constructor. Only that way autoloaded system classes would be available, I think. `Input` library should be autoloaded out of the box, though.

Comment: it's doesn't help any library or helper giving error. It's really odd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found fix. "I to i" from the URI in array cannot getting low letters like "uri" . It's changing the to urI from to core. System locale (for example mine tr_TR) causing the issue. I changed to en_US my locale in OS. It's fixing this, and there is also fix in core files. Adding mb_strtolower() to is_loaded() function in the common.php fixing issue.